# multer error boundary not found when request sent by node fetch but works when used with postman

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch, multer

I built up my node js server to save my images to a specific folder. It works fine when request is sent with Postman but it fails up when I use node-fetch.

```js
// server.js

const express = require("express")
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const multer = require("multer");

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, "public/resources/icons");
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, Buffer.from([file.originalname, Date.now()].join("_")).toString("base64")+".png");
    }
})

const upload = multer({storage});

const server = express();

server.post("/api/putFile", upload.single("image"), (req, res, forward) => {

    if(req.file) {
        res.json(JSON.stringify({path: req.file.filename}));
    } else {
        res.status(400).send("bad file type given in form")
    }
    
    forward();
});
```

```js
// server-utils.ts which is the file that requests to the server

export async function sendFile(file: File): Promise<{}> {
    const submitURL = "/api/putFile";
    const data: FormData = new FormData();


    const buffer = await file.arrayBuffer()
    data.append("image", Buffer.from(buffer).toString("binary"));

    return await fetch(submitURL, {
        method: "post",
        body: data,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        }

    }).then((response) => {
        return response.json();
    }).then(JSON.parse)

}
```

I've also tried to submit the `File` directly to the `FormData` as so : `data.append("image", file)` but the same error happens.

when I sent a Post request with postman as `multipart/form-data` it works well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `FormData` must be imported from node module `form-data`, otherwise, fetch won't be able to treat the request as multipart/form-data.
Then the `Content-Type` header must be removed so that fetch auto implements `Content-Type` header.

here is What to be changed :

```js
// server-utils.js

import fetch from "node-fetch"
import FormData from "form-data"

export async function sendFile(file: File): Promise<any> {
    const submitURL = "/api/putFile";
    const data: FormData = new FormData();

    data.append("image", file);

    return await fetch(submitURL, {
        method: "post",
        body: data,

    }).then((response) => {
        return response.json();
    }).then(JSON.parse)

}
```